# webview issue in android app

Tags: android, webview, viewport

i am designing an app common for both andorid and ios apps. In this in a particular activity i am loading an url which contains an image. The size of the image is to be as 
width - 960 and height - 640.

In the php code we have added the following line

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=320'/>
```

so that the webpage may get fitted within the screen size itself. This worked good for iPhone, whereas in android device i have loaded the page in a webview. My layout is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </WebView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

in my coding part is as follows

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);         
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxx.com/page/8");
```

But still in my 480x854 device on android 2.1 version i am getting some white spaces in the bottom and right corner of the web page

Where as in the WVGA854 emulator of android2.2 the view gets appeared with a horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

In all the android device i need the webpage to be exactly withing the screen size, without any white spaces or scroll bars.how to get this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some what i have managed the problem as follows

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        if(width == 320 || width == 360)
        {
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/get/6");
        }

        else if(width == 480)
        {
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(85);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/get/6");
        }
        else if(width == 540)
        {
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(90);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/get/6");
        }
        else if(width > 540)
        {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/get/6");
        }
        else
        {
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/get/6");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the viewport meta tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Its common for all devices. Did you try it. Did your issue got solved?

Comment: yes i am trying but no change while loading in webview, but when i enter in device browser it looks good in 2.1 and in 2.2(emulator) it looks over enlarged

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` attribute to the `WebView` xml description.